# sum three columns in three different tables using union query?

Tags: sql-server

i have tables t1 and t2 and t3 
my question is i want query  to sum three coumns (in and out and w ) in three table to be 135 
and i use these code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzDFI.jpg)

```
    select sum(x.aa)  from(
    SELECT SUM(t1.in)AS aa FROM t1

     union all 
      SELECT SUM(t2.out) AS aa FROM t2


union all 
      SELECT SUM(t3.w) AS aa FROM t3
      ) as x  
group by x.aa
```

Comment: What is your actual question?   Why are you using `GROUP BY` at the end of the query?

Comment: i want query to sum three coumns (in and out and w ) in three table to be 135

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you even need to use a `UNION` here.  You can just sum together three subqueries for each table sum:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(t1.in) FROM t1)  +
    (SELECT SUM(t2.out) FROM t2) +
    (SELECT SUM(t3.w) FROM t3) AS the_sum;
```

The `SUM()` function ignores `NULL` values, so nulls should not be a problem in each of the above three sums.  However, if every term in a sum be `NULL`, then the entire term would be `NULL`.  One way to get around this would be to use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t1.in), 0) FROM t1)  +
    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t2.out), 0) FROM t2) +
    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t3.w), 0) FROM t3) AS the_sum;
```

Comment: good but if i have select anther column in three tables where have same value

Comment: I don't understand this new requirement.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sums in one row, then the simplest way is probably to dispense with `union all`:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(t1.in) FROM t1) as sum_in,
       (SELECT SUM(t2.out) FROM t2) as sum_out,
       (SELECT SUM(t3.w) AS aa FROM t3) as sum_w;
```

Comment: @m.mahmoud . . . No.  Aggregation functions ignore `NULL` values.

Comment: @m.mahmoud . . . Then all the values in the table for the column are `NULL`.